# Processing data faster using ssis and an ssd drive

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssd, ssis, operating-system

We have a new local server that processes data using sql server 2008 and ssis. in this server i have dedicated drive to do different things. the c drive is for the os and software. the d drive is for db storage , and the ssis . The e drive is a ssd drive that we restore each database that is being used by the ssis.

our idea was that we process allot of data and since the ssd drive is only 500gb( because of the cost) we would have everything on a regular drive and transfer the databases in use to the ssd drive to have the process run faster.

when i run the ssis without the ssd drive it takes about 8 hrs and when i run the process restoring the databases on the ssd drive the process takes about the same amount of time to process( in fact if i include the restoring of the data bases the process takes longer) As of right now i cannot move the os and software to the ssd drive to test to see if that would help the process.

is there a way to utilize the ssd drive to process the data and to speed up the process.

Comment: Are you sure that storage is the bottleneck in your processing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a way to utilize the ssd drive to process the data and to speed up the process.

If storage speed ain't the problem, faster storage ain't the solution.

Use `perfmon`, SQL Server Profiler, or similar tools to figure out what the bottleneck actually is, then throw resources at that. If you're doing a lot of intensive computation, generally RAM and CPU will be the bottleneck - the solution is most commonly cleaning up the SQL, then throwing more CPU/RAM at the problem if the code is already reasonably efficient.